# Timer cancel method

Tags: java, timer

I have a question about the class java.util.Timer, specifically its `cancel()` method.

If I write code like this and call it 4000 times (for example), it won't stop executing, event it should I guess:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    private int id = ++TimerTest.counter;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(counter % 100 == 0)
            System.out.println("TimerTest #" + id + "\nI'm doing task: " + task);
        if(counter == 4000 && canceled == true){
            System.out.println("Canceling...");
            timer.cancel();
        }
    }
}, 0);
```

But instead of above script, I can change it to:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    private int id = ++TimerTest.counter;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(counter % 100 == 0)
            System.out.println("TimerTest #" + id + "\nI'm doing task: " + task);
        if(counter == 4000 && canceled == true){
            System.out.println("Canceling...");
        }
    }
}, 0);
timer.cancel();
```

I was looking for the same problem description but I didn't come across anything special :)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Your first example cancels the timer when the counter reaches 4000 *and* the `canceled` variable becomes `true`.  Where / when does canceled become true?

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be in that you appear to be calling the Timer 4000 times. Instead you should have 1 Timer and schedule a period with it. Call the

```
public void schedule(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)
```

Method instead of

```
public void schedule(TimerTask task, long delay)
```

Here is an example of it being used correctly:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class TimerTest {

    private static int counter = 0;

    private void doTimer() throws InterruptedException {
        Timer timer = new Timer();

        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                counter ++;
                System.out.println("TimerTest #" + counter + " I'm doing task");    
            }
        }, 0,1000);

        //Sleep for 10 seconds before cancelling the timer
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(10000);
        System.out.println("Timer cancelled");
        timer.cancel();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        new TimerTest().doTimer();
    }

}
```

This stops the Timer after 10 seconds:

```
TimerTest #1 I'm doing task
TimerTest #2 I'm doing task
TimerTest #3 I'm doing task
TimerTest #4 I'm doing task
TimerTest #5 I'm doing task
TimerTest #6 I'm doing task
TimerTest #7 I'm doing task
TimerTest #8 I'm doing task
TimerTest #9 I'm doing task
TimerTest #10 I'm doing task
Timer cancelled
```